# How to Perform an NIntegrate for an Interpolating Function?

Tags: numerical-integration, interpolation

```
S[w_, l_, m_, mi_, ma_] := {
  so = NSolve[{r + 2 m*Log[r/(2 m) - 1] == mi}, r];
  bd = r /. so;
  
  sol =
   NDSolve[{\[Phi]''[
        s] + (w^2 - (R[s] - 2*m)/
           R[s]*((l*(l + 1))/R[s]^2 + (2*m)/R[s]^3)) \[Phi][s] == 0, 
     R'[s] == 1 - (2*m)/R[s], \[Phi][mi] == 1, \[Phi]'[mi] == -I*w, 
     R[mi] == bd[[1]]}, {\[Phi], R}, {s, mi, ma}];
  Pfun = \[Phi] /. sol[[1, 1]];
  Rfun = R /. sol[[1, 2]];
  Abs[Exp[-2*I*w*ma]*(I*w*Pfun[ma] + Pfun'[ma])/(
    I*w*Pfun[ma] - Pfun'[ma])]
  }
tbl = Table[{x, S[x, 0.1, 1, -40, 40]}, {x, 0, 1, 1/20}];
pol = Interpolation[tbl];
NIntegrate[pol[z]*Exp[-I*z], {z, 0, 1}]
```

**My question is how to do a NIntegrate for pol[z]*Exp[-I*z]?**
**I know I can do a Integrate for pol[z], but I don't know why I cannot do a NIntegrate for pol[z]?**

Answer (score 1):

"S" returns a list, not a number. Therefore, extract the element:

```
S[w_, l_, m_, mi_, 
  ma_] := {so = NSolve[{r + 2 m*Log[r/(2 m) - 1] == mi}, r];
   bd = r /. so;
   sol = 
    NDSolve[{\[Phi]''[
         s] + (w^2 - (R[s] - 2*m)/
             R[s]*((l*(l + 1))/R[s]^2 + (2*m)/R[s]^3)) \[Phi][s] == 0,
       R'[s] == 1 - (2*m)/R[s], \[Phi][mi] == 1, \[Phi]'[mi] == -I*w, 
      R[mi] == bd[[1]]}, {\[Phi], R}, {s, mi, ma}];
   Pfun = \[Phi] /. sol[[1, 1]];
   Rfun = R /. sol[[1, 2]];
   Abs[Exp[-2*I*w*
       ma]*(I*w*Pfun[ma] + Pfun'[ma])/(I*w*Pfun[ma] - Pfun'[ma])]}[[1]]
tbl = Table[{x, S[x, 0.1, 1, -40, 40]}, {x, 0, 1, 1/20}];
pol = Interpolation[tbl];
NIntegrate[pol[z]*Exp[-I*z], {z, 0, 1}]

0.185301 - 0.0210933 I
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$Version

(* "13.3.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 24, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]
```

To group expressions, use parentheses rather than list brackets.

Functions that use numeric techniques should have their arguments restricted to numeric values.

```
S[w_?NumericQ, l_?NumericQ, m_?NumericQ,
  mi_?NumericQ, ma_?NumericQ] :=
 (so = NSolve[{r + 2 m*Log[r/(2 m) - 1] == mi}, r];
   bd = r /. so;
   sol = NDSolve[{
      ϕ''[s] + (w^2 - (R[s] - 2*m)/R[s]*
            ((l*(l + 1))/R[s]^2 + (2*m)/R[s]^3)) ϕ[s] == 0,
      R'[s] == 1 - (2*m)/R[s], ϕ[mi] == 1, ϕ'[mi] == -I*w,
      R[mi] == bd[[1]]}, {ϕ, R}, {s, mi, ma}];
   Pfun = ϕ /. sol[[1, 1]];
   Rfun = R /. sol[[1, 2]];
   Abs[Exp[-2*I*w*ma]*(I*w*Pfun[ma] + Pfun'[ma])/
      (I*w*Pfun[ma] - Pfun'[ma])]) // Quiet

tbl = Table[{x, S[x, 1/10, 1, -40, 40]}, {x, 0, 1, 1/20}];

pol = Interpolation[tbl];

NIntegrate[pol[z]*Exp[-I*z], {z, 0, 1}]

(* 0.185301 - 0.0210933 I *)
```